# maven-jar-plugin does not generate MANIFEST

Tags: java, maven-3, manifest.mf

I cant generate MANIFEST file using maven...
I try everything and I didnt find the solution.
The jar file is generate correct, but manifest is missing.

This is the part of my pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <useDefaultManifestFile> true </useDefaultManifestFile>
                <!-- archive> <manifest> <mainClass>net.menago.core.main.Menago</mainClass> 
                    </manifest> 
                </archive -->
                <!-- archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <mode>development</mode>
                        <url>${project.url}</url>
                        <key>value</key>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see there are some commented codes which does not work too.
I've tried mvn clean install, compile, package...

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: remove comment from `archive` tag.

Comment: When you tested it, did you have two "manifest" elements as you do in your example or were you only using one at a time? You have one commented out here and then one farther down.

Comment: Only one at time. 
I've started with basic conf:
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
<useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
</configuration>
and it does not work, then I start to test different things.
In maven logs I have no warnings

Comment: Please put your project on Github (or may be a reduced example which reproduces the problem) and give a link so someone can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your packaging element has the value bundle set to it

```
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${java.version}</source>
      <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this will work

```
<configuration> 
                    <archive> 
                      <manifest> <mainClass>net.menago.core.main.Menago</mainClass>                                  
                        <index>true</index>                  
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>                   
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <mode>development</mode>
                            <url>${project.url}</url>
                            <key>value</key>
                        </manifestEntries>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>
      </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks.
I put <index> before <manifest> due to build errors. In a results I had no error and still no MANIFEST file.

Comment: @Oleksandr Papchenko - It does not.

Answer (score -2):

Clearly your pasted segment will not work due to the comments, so I make the assumption that you have posted what you have to show what you have been trying to use.

The correct usage of `<manifestEntries>` is as so:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <yourKey>your value</yourKey>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

This is at odds with your concurrent use of `<useDefaultManifestFile>` which will produce a standard output.